# add module "spring integration redis" which print out "XXX is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-data-redis-reactive

I am integrating the spring integration-redis module so as to use the RedisLockRegistry. but I got the following logs on spring boot start up.

```
19: 2020/09/11 21:02:25,006 2312 [INFO] [main] [integration.config.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.registerErrorChannel(DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java:213)] : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
21: 2020/09/11 21:02:25,012 2318 [INFO] [main] [integration.config.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.registerTaskScheduler(DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java:300)] : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
23: 2020/09/11 21:02:25,015 2321 [INFO] [main] [integration.config.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.registerHeaderChannelRegistry(DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java:460)] : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
25: 2020/09/11 21:02:25,073 2379 [INFO] [main] [context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:335)] : Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
27: 2020/09/11 21:02:25,115 2421 [INFO] [main] [context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:335)] : Bean 'integrationChannelResolver' of type [org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
29: 2020/09/11 21:02:25,119 2425 [INFO] [main] [context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:335)] : Bean 'integrationDisposableAutoCreatedBeans' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.Disposables] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

1.how to create errorChannel bean, taskScheduler bean and ThreadPoolTaskScheduler bean so that I can get grid of these info like warning?

2.do the IntegrationManagementConfiguration, integrationChannelResolver and integrationDisposableAutoCreatedBeans cause problem to my application?

3.how to fixed these situation for the following logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are just INFO log messages. Fully harmless. you probably didn't turn on the INFO for the whole `org.springframework` category to see much more similar messages from other projects.

In fact the first 3 just say us that default bean are going to be created. We may consider to move those messages to the DEBUG or even TRACE level though...

The one for the `IntegrationManagementConfiguration` doesn't matter because this one is a `@Configuration` class and probably no one of them "is eligible for getting processed".
The last one for the `Disposables` also doesn't matter since this class is package protected and no one really is going to post-process it somehow.

The most dangerous in your logs is that one for the `BeanFactoryChannelResolver`, but as long as you use whatever the framework provides for you everything is going to be good.